# [SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 298.674 while invoking driver.get() method of selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to open the Url using below method .But it takes long time to load the Url however it is test environment Url.

```
@BeforeClass    
public void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");       
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");         
driver.manage().window().maximize();         
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
}
```

To load the Url using `driver.get("XXXXXX")` method takes around 4    minutes which throws Exception below

> Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68
>   (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 6967 Only local
>   connections are allowed. Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and
>   related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code. Apr 20,
>   2019 3:59:52 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Detected dialect: OSS [1555756492.787][SEVERE]:
>   Timed out receiving message from renderer: 298.674
>   [1555756492.795][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer:
>   -0.008 FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setup org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout   (Session info:
>   chrome=73.0.3683.103)   (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68
>   (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 300.02 seconds Build info:
>   version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info:
>   host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
>   'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0,
>   pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP,
>   acceptSslCerts=false,
>   goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:51331},
>   acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore, applicationCacheEnabled=false,
>   rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=73.0.3683.68
>   (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),
>   userDataDir=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir2592_17813},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   strictFileInteractability=false, databaseEnabled=false,
>   handlesAlerts=true, version=73.0.3683.103,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy=Proxy(), nativeEvents=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   f2e4b8e52414566b01dff2c0ba9f7ce4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS 
[1555756492.787][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 298.674 
[1555756492.795][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.008 
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setup org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout 
 (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103) 
 (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 300.02 seconds 
 Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' 
 System info: host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Web Browsing Session* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *ChromeDriver* version is **73.0.3683.68**.
- Your *Chrome* version is **73.0.3683.103**.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_121** which is pretty *old* and *ancient*.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68*, *Chrome v73.0.3683.103* and *JDK v8u121*.

---

### Solution

Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u202](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).